# How are TLEs updated?

Tags: orbital-elements

I understand that TLEs are used with SGP to predict future positions/velocities of a Earth-orbiting satellite. However, how are these sets obtained in the first place? Is it based on ground observations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes. The U.S. Air Force uses the [Space Surveillance Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Space_Surveillance_Network) to track all observable objects in space. They have a system in place which attempts to correlate tracks with existing objects.

If the system encounters tracks which do not match up with an existing object, they create a new object to track. The system then continues to correlate tracks to this new object. After collecting multiple tracks (which could take a few days depending on the geometry of the orbit), the object is assigned a static catalog ID number, and finally released to the public (assuming they designate the object as unclassified).

I simplified the process somewhat, but that's the general idea.